# How to setup J2EE aplication (ear) to use shared JSF and JSTL libraries in weblogic 11g?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jstl, weblogic11g

I'm trying to deploy J2EE application to Weblogic. It consists of web-module and ejb-module.
My web-module uses JSF 1.2 and JSTL 1.2.
I've deployed both libraries to Weblogic and then point my WebModule to use these libraries
in weblogic.xml

```
    <weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0
 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

 <context-root>/dailyplanner</context-root>

 <library-ref>
  <library-name>jsf</library-name>
  <specification-version>1.2</specification-version>
  <implementation-version>1.2</implementation-version>
  <exact-match>false</exact-match>
 </library-ref>

 <library-ref>
  <library-name>jstl</library-name>
  <specification-version>1.2</specification-version>
  <implementation-version>1.2</implementation-version>
  <exact-match>false</exact-match>
 </library-ref>
    </weblogic-web-app>
```

All works fine, if I deploy only WebModule as a standalone application.

Then I've set up the whole application to use these libraries with the following code in weblogic-application.xml (which is inside ejb/META-INF)

```
<weblogic-application xmlns="ttp://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0
 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd">

 <library-ref>
  <library-name>jsf</library-name>
  <specification-version>1.2</specification-version>
  <implementation-version>1.2</implementation-version>
  <exact-match>false</exact-match>
 </library-ref>

 <library-ref>
  <library-name>jstl</library-name>
  <specification-version>1.2</specification-version>
  <implementation-version>1.2</implementation-version>
  <exact-match>false</exact-match>
 </library-ref>
</weblogic-application>
```

But If I try to deploy the whole J2EE application (ear file) now, weblogic will fail to deploy it due to missing JSF and JSTL classes.

What should I do to point my J2EE application to use shared JSF and JSTL libraries in weblogic?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try keeping the configuration in the war inside the ear.

Comment: Can you explain, what you mean, plase? I'm not sure, I understand you.

Comment: Instead of moving the configuration to the ear level, leave it in the web module level. As you have in the first example, in the WEB-INF/weblogic.xml of the web module.

Comment: But configuration is still there. I've just doubled it in ear level, assuming that this will not break anything. I'm going to try now leave configuration only in one place.

Comment: Then is more strange. Does it appears well configured in the WL console? You can check it by going to Deployments/jsf and at the bottom you have "Applications that reference this Library" It should appear your application

Comment: Applications that reference this Library
DailyPlannerEJB - Enterprise Application

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace?